# Boostrap launch modal and display specific tabbed content pane

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 to build a website. I am launching a modal which includes some tabs. Is there anyway I can call to launch the modal and specify which tab should be rendered open on modal launch?

I am using standard modal launch code e.g.

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2launch"
```

Then standard Boostrap code for tabs e.g.

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
```

So, i'd like to be able to say, launch modal called "modal2launch" with "tab2" open...

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tab pane is inside the modal body then simply set the `active` class on the tab2 and remove the `active` class from the other tabs.

If you have a set case of needing to set it to tab2 then you can use javascript to activate the tab inside the modal `shown.bs.modal`

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
    $('#myTab a:first').tab('show') // Select first tab
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show') // Select last tab
    $('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show') // Select third tab (0-indexed)
})
```

As you haven't provided much code I have used the examples at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs and http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals to give you an idea

Comment: Thanks, but I have 2 tabs of content in the modal and 2 buttons to launch the modal - so button 1 launches the modal with tab 1 in view, button 2 launches the modal with tab 2 in view.

Comment: You will need to post more code then if you are wanting more help.

Comment: Thanks, worked it out - had to use some custom jQuery - just thought there might be something out of the Bootstrap box to make this work.

Comment: @dubbs If you've worked out a solution, post it and then accept it, or if this is the answer that worked for you, mark it as accepted.